# Apache vhost resolves to localhost document root

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-11.10, virtual-hosts, apache2.2

I downloaded apache2.2.22 src from http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi and made the installation. The installation works fine. But the problem arises when I try adding vhosts. I added 2 virtual hosts 
1. localhost 
2. someother.localhost 
Both point to different document roots, but resolve to the doc root of the first virtualhost.

hereis my vhost file,

> NameVirtualHost *:80
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
>     DocumentRoot "/webserver/htdocs"
>     ServerName localhost
>     ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error_log"
>     CustomLog "logs/localhost-access_log" common
> </VirtualHost>
> <Directory /home/sourabhn/somepath>
>     Options FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
>     DocumentRoot "/home/sourabhn/somepath"
>     ServerName someother.localhost
>     ErrorLog "logs/someother-localhost-error_log"
>     CustomLog "logs/someother-localhost-access_log" common
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

I have made the appropriate entry in the hosts file. I am running a Ubuntu 11.10 machine. Please get back with your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right away I noticed a difference between your file and the one I cobbled together from net tutorials like this from [bobpeers](http://bobpeers.com/linux/apache_virtual_hosts). I've added within the virtual host block the `<Directory>` block.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/
ServerName xtiansimonslaptop.local
    <Directory "/var/www/">
        Allow from all
        Options +Includes +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm working on Drupal and just so I can get a name resolved to the Drupal directory, it will take care of the rest. In the Drupal install I have several projects each with their own domain name set up in one Drupal installtion. Below is the example of a Drupal site named hello.local, and another of my Drupal sites could be cheese.local. Both pointing to the same Directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php/drupal7
    ServerName hello.local
#   ServerAlias *.hello.local
        <Directory "/var/www/php/drupal7">
            Allow from all
            Options +Includes +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Right now its working save for the commented line ServerAlias. Which brings up another point I learned about setting up vHosts. The /etc/hosts file is important to get set up properly.

In the example by bobpeers you'll see their hosts entry example,

```
ServerName bobpeers.live
ServerName bobpeers.dev
```

I would expect the reverse name `live.bobpeers.local` to be a clearer example of a server name. And this is the thing--I find there is inconsistency in examples. Some examples simply do not use key terms like `.local` or follow the generic signature `sub-domain.domaon.com`. Copying one persons non-normal example you may think the above ServerName references two virtual hosts, live.local and dev.local. For all I know, maybe they do!

One more thing about vHosts. The man page shows this,

```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   192.168.1.10    foo.mydomain.org       foo
   192.168.1.13    bar.mydomain.org       bar
```

What works for my localhost sandbox is this,

```
   127.0.0.1    localhost
   127.0.0.1    mydomain.local           mydomain
   127.0.0.1    foo.mydomain.local       foo
   127.0.0.1    bar.mydomain.local       bar
```

Which seems correct since name based is supposed to sort it all out, and not this 192.168.1.x IP Mask nonsense. (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

My advice : 
Declare a "global" ServerName and a global DocumentRoot,
Then use only the core directive ServerAlias in your vhost http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias.